# REGEX: Delete all extra inverted commas/quotes from a particular html tag

Tags: notepad++, regex

In the example below, you will see a extra comma after word wife. That is extra, and I must delete those kind of commas from all such tags

```
<meta name="description" content="My name is Prince, I have a wife " nice, which is reckoned a marriage good ."/>
```

My regex is not very good. DOn't know why.

**FIND:** `<meta name="description" content="(?:")?>(.*?)"/>`

Comment: Extra `"`'s it looks like

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<meta name="description" content="|\G(?!^)).*?\K["]+(?=.*?"/>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.